# edge blur in cycles render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, blur

Having trouble with unwanted edge blur in cycles render. No motion blur is enabled. [image]

Thanks for your help,
Rick

Comment: Need more information. Looks like it might be JPG compression. What does it look like in the Render Preview view.

Answer (score 2):

You are probably displaying a zoomed-in render result. In the UV/Image Editor window, where your render is displayed, go to *View* > *Zoom 1:1* (equivalent: <kbd>Numpad 1</kbd>). That should fix it.

[image]